# Can a port or cable damage a motherboard?

Tags: macos, mac, cable, adapter

I have a 2018 Mac mini.

I have already had it repaired 2 times for the exact same problem.

After a certain point it stopped showing picture through its HDMI port on startup. Then if I disconnected and reconnected any part of the connection between the machine and the monitor there would be picture again until the next startup.

They said that the they had to replace the motherboard each time for the fact that it was not giving picture through the HDMI port.

The last time I was told by the service team that it is actually very hard to damage a motherboard so I should suspect an issue with the adapters I am using.

Is it even possible that a cable or adapter, or even the monitor can do harm to my motherboard?

I have a DVI male > HDMI male cable. I tried 2 different of this type. I also have a DVI male-to-male cable and a DVI female > HDMI male adapter for it. Each of them produce the same issue after a given time. Weird enough, even if the DVI connection stops working, monitors attached using an HDMI male-to-male cable still work.

Or maybe I should only use Apple branded adapters?

I am also suspecting that it may be the software update that is causing the issue since this problem always starts during an update.

I have given up hope, I have no idea what the problem is.

Comment: @Smock - "father" would imply a male connector while "mother" would be a female connector.  In traditional American/British English, father would be the male, while mother would be female.

Comment: Using only Apple branded adapters, you will be in a stronger position if this happens again, when repairing.

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot of fake HDMI cables and adapters. The HDMI consortium only certifies HDMI male-to-male cables. If anything has an HDMI male connector on it, the other end MUST be another HDMI male connector; otherwise it does not meet the requirements for HDMI certification and cannot use the official HDMI logotype. An HDMI-certified HDMI-to-DVI adapter can only have an HDMI female connector (for use with a separate HDMI male-to-male cable). Consider replacing all the fake HDMI stuff you have with real HDMI certified equipment bearing the real logo.

Comment: @Ramhound well that's one interpretation. The implication of parenthood though could also represent a splitter cable - a father(1x male) having two sons (split to 2x male) etc - much like a motherboard may have several daughterboards. It's been edited to male now anyway so there's no ambiguity left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**

A defective cable/adapter is very well capable of damaging ports and or other parts of your system. It doesn't happen often but when it does happen it can be hard to detect.

A good example which might apply to you would be a cable with an internal break in it causing it to short. Power flows over the wrong pin and the chip behind the port gets damaged but not enough to instantly break down.

Try a new cable and see how that fares.